# Iterate between two dates till first date is before the second

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two dates in unix:

```
let start: number = 1632988953;
const end: number  = 1638259353;
```

I need to iterate over this two dates, witch will calculate the new `start` date in each iteration.

So, I have a `while` structure like below:

```
const datesArray = [];
while (start <= end) {
    let newDate = dayjs.unix(start).add(5, 'day').unix();

    datesArray.push(newDate);
    
    start = newDate;
}
```

When I start this `while` in the function, it iterates infinitely killing my browser, can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working fine, execute the snippet to see for yourself

```js
let start = 1632988953;
const end  = 1638259353;

let condition = true;
console.log("before : ",condition);
const datesArray = [];
while (start <= end) {
    let newDate = dayjs.unix(start).add(5, 'day').unix();
    datesArray.push(newDate);
    start = newDate;
    condition = start <= end;
}
console.log("after : ",condition);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script>dayjs().format()</script>
```

Comment: It works for me as well. Here is my example in typescript: https://codepen.io/jonas_weinhardt/pen/RwgdaKx?editors=0010

Comment: ohh i see it after create this post :D sometimes we have a solution to problem instant after ask about solution :)